# Image not appearing In compiled PDF

Tags: graphics

So I have added in an Image to my document. the Image is saved in the same location as the .tex doc and I think the code I put in is right but the image still does not appear.

Here's my code for the image:

```
In figure~\ref{figimage}\footnote{
}

\begin{figure}[h!]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.5\columnwidth]{image}\\
    \caption{Terminator\newline 
    (Free image \url{http://imageurl)
    \label{figimage}
\end{figure}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Do you get any error message or warning?

Comment: Yes I get two: line 159: File `image' not found. \includegraphics {image} and
line 159: There's no line here to end. \includegraphics {image}\\

Comment: For "Thre's no line here to end" suppres "\\" after `includegraphics`.

Comment: The argument to `\includegraphics` must be a file name (without extension) pointing to the real image file you have to include.

Comment: What kind of image (pdf, png, gif, jpg,...) do you have? Which compiler (latex, pdflatex, lualatex, ...) do you use?

Comment: its a .jpg image

Comment: I have made the changes suggested here but it still says no file found Is there any reason I'm pretty certain its in the right folder

Comment: Hi Aaron. Have you checked that the capitalization of the file name matches the one in your TeX file and the file extension of the file is ".jpg" and not ".JPG" or ".JPEG" or ".jpeg"?